# Workflow Foundation for Scheduled Process

Tags: workflow-foundation

Is Workflow Foundation a good option for creating a scheduled process for a customer rebilling solution? The process needs to run daily and interact with a data layer as well as a web service. In the past, I have defaulted to using SSIS and either a Scheduled Task or SQL Server Agent job to handle the scheduling.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Channel 9 (endpoint.tv) there are two webcasts that address a scenario where Workflow Foundation is used for a batch job implementation.

- [Workflow Services as a Batch Job](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Workflow-Services-as-a-Batch-Job/)
- [AppFabric AutoStart and WF4 Batch Job Example](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-AppFabric-AutoStart-and-WF4-Batch-Job-Example/)

I have used WF myself for some simple scheduled processes inside a Windows service and I must say that I'm very satisfied with the result.

Comment: Ronald, thanks for your response. I will review the links you provided. From your personal experience, do you find it overkill to use WF to create a simple process? This process would basically need to do the following: 1) Retrieve a list of clients that need to be charged, 2) iterate through the list and call a web service for each client, 3) notify each client.  I feel like there should be a simple solution to such a simple process, but I always end up using an SSIS package and it feels like overkill.

Comment: I definitely do not think it overkill for such a process. WF has support for error handling and parallelization and I think you can make good use of both. E.g. suppose your web service is temporarily unavailable, what to do then? And all clients can be processed in parallel.